How to define an interface for methods marked with [RelayCommand]
My team requires interfaces for our ViewModels. I love the MVVM Community Toolkit but I want to use both interfaces and [RelayCommand] Attributed class methods.
How do I define an interface for DownloadConfigurationCommand in the following scenario using my ObservableObject descendant class?
The following generates a 'Command' that is public called:
DownloadConfigurationCommand

The code is defined as:
 [RelayCommand]
private async Task DownloadConfiguration(AppConfiguration appConfiguration)
{
    // TODO: Call DownloadConfiguration Configuration
    await Task.Delay(10);
}

FYI: The code works but misses the Team requirement of having an interface defined.
Thanks in advance!

If you really want to define the exact specification of your command in an interface, in your case both asynchronous and having a typed parameter, you could specify the property as IAsyncRelayCommand<T> but this ties you to a specific implementation, thus negating any possible reason for using an interface in the first place. If you want to keep things more generic, just declare it as ICommand and lose the ability to specify the exact type of command.
In general though, there is no point in defining an interface for a type that you're only ever going to implement once. It sounds like the policy of an over pedantic manager, who doesn't really understand why they're doing.

Well the use case is that we do Unit Testing and Mocking using NSubstitute

What is there to substitute for a ViewModel? It makes sense to mock out any injected services, but not the VM itself.
